# TideSDK - How get filename that contains reserved Word on MAC OS

Tags: tidesdk

I'm using TideSDK on Mac OS X.

I'm trying to open a file that contains the dollar sign on its name. Like for exemple:

"Total Balance $100.txt"

I'm using the function like this:

Ti.Filesystem.getFile(path + "Total Balance $100.txt")

The result is file not found. I tried to use:

'$100' and \$100 and \$100 and "$100" and "\$100" but no success...

How may I get the file?

Thank you